# How do OIDC servers (specifically KeyCloak) know how to respond to a token refresh request?

Tags: oauth, keycloak, openid-connect

I am using KeyCloak as an authentication server for my web app.

I have run into a situation where occasionally, during token refresh, the sub value of the response does not match the sub value send in the request.

I have decoded both the refresh token sent in the request, and the access token returned in the response, the following is the refresh token with each property marked with if the response access token is the same or not.

```
{
  "iat": Different,
  "jti": Different,
  "iss": Same,
  "aud": Same,
  "sub": Different,
  "typ": Different,
  "azp": Same,
  "nonce": Same,
  "session_state": Same,
  "scope": Same,
  "sid": Same
}
```

In addition, the access token returns the user info for the new sub rather than the one send in the request.

How do OIDC servers determine the user the token is for? Is it based on the nonce? I did notice that all refresh requests are using the same nonce so perhaps that is causing it to mix up the users?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that KeyCloak was assigning the same session ID to multiple users of the same PC due to a security vulnerability in a previous version.

https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-97g8-xfvw-q4hg